# how can I separate the incorrect password and incorrect email when logging in?

Tags: php, html, css, mysql

```
if(isset($_POST['login'])){  
    $user_email=$_POST['email'];  
    $user_pass=$_POST['pass'];  

    $check_user="select * from users WHERE email='$user_email'AND pass='$user_pass'";  

    $run=mysqli_query($dbcon,$check_user);  

    if(mysqli_num_rows($run)){  
        echo "<script>window.open('welcome.php','_self')</script>";
        $_SESSION['email']=$user_email; 
    }else{  
        echo "<script>alert('Email or password is incorrect!')</script>";  
    }
}
?>
```

instead of Email or password is incorrect.. it should be specific if the email is incorrect then it should only be  email is incorrect same in password

Comment: saving plane password is very bad idea. Use `passord-hashing` mecahnism  for password

Comment: You have several flaws in your code:
You should use **prepared statement** to prevent sql injection. 
and, most importantly please use [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [password_verify](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) to store & authenticate user password.

then you can check if email exist in `users` table, if it doesn't exist then email is invalid....If it exists then check password against it, if it not matched then password is invalid....

But I **wouldn't** recommend this separate warning system.

Comment: It's doable. But it should be mentioned that security professionals would advise against the practice. If you tell people that their only their email is incorrect, you've just told an attacker that someone is using that password!

Comment: From a security standpoint you shouldn't specify which is incorrect, just that there is a mismatch.

Comment: @gilliduck is right. Suppose a hacker wants to break into the system. Then  giving them an error message like "yes, there is a user with this password, now all you need to do is guess the username" will actually help them break in!

Answer (score 1):

This will help you.

```
if(isset($_POST['login']))  
  {  
    $user_email=$_POST['email'];  
    $user_pass=$_POST['pass'];  

    $check_user="select * from users WHERE email='$user_email'";  

    $run=mysqli_query($dbcon,$check_user);  

    if(mysqli_num_rows($run))  
    {  
      $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run);
      if($_POST['pass'] == $row['pass'])
        {
            echo "<script>window.open('welcome.php','_self')</script>";  
            $_SESSION['email']=$user_email;
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<script>alert('Password is incorrect!')</script>";  
        }
    }
    else  
    {  
    echo "<script>alert('Email is incorrect!')</script>";  
    }
  }
```

**Its Just a logical way please secure your password..... thanks**

Comment: how is the condition for 'PSSWORD_FROM_DATABASE'

Comment: use "$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run);"  by whoch you get your users value in $row. then you compare.

Answer (score 0):

**Suggestions**

- Use PDO ( to avoid sql injection )
- Use password hashing ( don't use plain password )

> how can I separate the incorrect password and incorrect email when
>   logging in?

```
if(isset($_POST['login']))
{ 

    $user_email=$_POST['email'];  
    $user_pass=$_POST['pass'];  

    if(!filter_var($user_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) 
    {
       // Use your error handling ;)
       // exit('Invalid email address');
    }

    $sql_check_email = "select * from users WHERE email='$user_email'"
    $run=mysqli_query($dbcon,$sql_check_email);  

// check email exists 
if(mysqli_num_rows($run))
{  

     $check_user="select * from users WHERE email='$user_email' AND pass='$user_pass'";  
     $run=mysqli_query($dbcon,$check_user);  

   if(mysqli_num_rows($run))
   {  

    // successful
    echo "<script>window.open('welcome.php','_self')</script>";
    $_SESSION['email']=$user_email; 

   }else
   {  
    echo "<script>alert('Password is incorrect!')</script>";  
   }

}else
{
    // do your error dandling here
   // email id not exists in users table
  // exit('No such email address, probably your account not exists');
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by querying the email from the database first, if the email is there then check if the password for that email is correct.

This way you can check if each one is correct separately.

for example :

```
if(isset($_POST['login']))  
{  
    $user_email=$_POST['email'];  
    $user_pass=$_POST['pass'];  

    $check_user="select * from users WHERE email='$user_email'"; // email only  

    $run=mysqli_query($dbcon,$check_user);  

    if(mysqli_num_rows($run))  
    {  
       $result = mysql_fetch_assoc($run); 

       if ($result[0]['password'] == $user_pass)
       {
           echo "<script>window.open('welcome.php','_self')</script>";  

           $_SESSION['email']=$user_email;
       } else {
           echo "<script>alert('Password is incorrect!')</script>"; 
       }

    }  
    else  
    {  
       echo "<script>alert('Email is incorrect!')</script>";  
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution: 
Ask the database for a single record matching the email then check the password.

Notes:

1. never write plaintext passwords to the database.  Libsodium is the preferred encryption library for passwords.
2. emails can come in with random casing and extra spaces, best to remove both.
3. recommend add unique unique index on email field in users table.  otherwise you will allow multiple results.
4. as a double check, I usually add LIMIT 1 to this type of queries.
5. `fields` should be escaped with `.
6. better to use parameterized queries instead of passing in the actual email.

Code:

```
if (isset($_POST['login'])) {  
  $user_email = strtolower(trim($_POST['email']));  
  $user_pass  = $_POST['pass'];  

  $check_user = "SELECT `email`, `pass` FROM `users` WHERE `email` = '{$user_email}' LIMIT 1";

  $result = mysqli_query($dbcon, $check_user);
  $user = mysqli_fetch_row($result);

  // please encrypt the password (best with Sodium in php 7.2)
  $enc_pass = encrypt_password($user_pass);

  // separate errors - note: best practice is single error (security pov)
  if (!$user) {
    echo "<script>alert('Email is incorrect!')</script>";  
  } else if ($user['pass'] != $enc_pass) {
    echo "<script>alert('Password is incorrect!')</script>";  
  } else {
    echo "<script>window.open('welcome.php','_self')</script>";  
    $_SESSION['email'] = $user_email; 
  }
}
```

Comment: how do i encrypt the password?

Comment: libsodium documentation for up to php 7.1 uses the \Sodium namespace .  in php 7.2 and beyond it uses just sodium_ or SODIUM_ prefixes.  here is the github project: https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium-php

Answer (score 0):

```
you can separate check email and password if it is valid or not
$err1=$err2="";
if(isset($_POST['login'])){  
    $user_email=$_POST['email'];  
    $user_pass=$_POST['pass'];  
    $email_check_qry = "SELECT count(id) AS cnt FROM users WHERE email='$user_email'";
$run_qry1=mysqli_query($dbcon,$email_check_qry );

if(!mysqli_num_rows($run_qry1))
{
$err1=1;
?>
<script>
alert("incorrect email");
</script>
<?php
}
else
{
 $err1 = "";
}
  $pass_check_qry = "SELECT count(id) AS cnt FROM users WHERE pass='$user_pass'";
$run_qry2=mysqli_query($dbcon,$email_check_qry );

if(!mysqli_num_rows($run_qry2))
{
$err2=1;
?>
<script>
alert("incorrect pass");
</script>
<?php
}
else
{
 $err2 = "";
}  
if(!$err1 || !$err2)
{
    $check_user="select * from users WHERE email='$user_email'AND pass='$user_pass'";  

    $run=mysqli_query($dbcon,$check_user);  

    if(mysqli_num_rows($run)){  
        echo "<script>window.open('welcome.php','_self')</script>";
        $_SESSION['email']=$user_email; 
    }else{  
        echo "<script>alert('Email or password is incorrect!')</script>";  
    }
}
}
?>
```